# Smooth transition between fiber elements in pst-optexp

Tags: pst-optexp

Hei,
I am trying to draw a small fiber-optical design using `pst-optexp`, but I'm currently stuck with some problems. My MWE code is

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](16,6)
        \psset[optexp]{fiber=none, usefiberstyle}
        \newpsstyle{Fiber}{linecolor=orange, linewidth=2\pslinewidth}
        \pnodes(9, 4){TSFIn}(11, 4){TSFOut}
        \pnodes(14, 4){LoopIn}(14, 2){LoopOut}
        \pnodes(9, 1){OutputIsolatorIn}(11,1){OutputIsolatorOut}
        \pnodes(13, 2){OutputSplitter}(16, 3){LaserOutHigh}(16, 1){LaserOutLow}
        %Element 1
        \optfiber[compname=ActiveFiber, position=start,linecolor=red](TSFIn)(TSFOut){Active fiber}
        %Element 2
        \optcoupler[compname=FiberLoopCoupler](TSFOut)(OutputIsolatorIn)(LoopIn)(LoopOut){\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Fiber\\loop\\coupler\end{tabular}}
        %Element 3
        \optisolator[compname=OutputIsolator](OutputIsolatorIn)(OutputIsolatorOut){\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Output\\Isolator\end{tabular}}
        %Element 4
        \wdmsplitter[compname=OutputSplitter, coupleralign=bottom](OutputIsolatorOut)(LaserOutHigh)(LaserOutLow){Output splitter}
        \optfiber[compname=FiberLoop, addtoFiberOut={ncurv=1,angleB=0},addtoFiberIn={ncurv=1,angleA=0},compshift=-1,label=-1.5.l](LoopIn)(LoopOut){\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Fiber\\Loop\end{tabular}}
        \drawfiber{1}{2}
        \drawfiber[fiberangleA=0, fiberangleB=180, ncurv=1]{2}(\oenodeIn{OutputIsolator})
        \drawfiber{2}(\oenodeIn{FiberLoop})
        \drawfiber[startnode=1](\oenodeOut{FiberLoop}){2}
        \drawfiber(\oenodeOut{OutputIsolator})(\oenodeIn{OutputSplitter})
        \drawfiber[fiberangleA=0, fiberangleB=0, ncurv=1.2](\oenodeOut{OutputSplitter})(LaserOutHigh)
        \drawfiber[fiberangleA=0, fiberangleB=0, ncurv=1.2](\oenodeOut{OutputSplitter})(LaserOutLow)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

and the result is
[image]
Now, I have several issues which I was not able to solve until now:

- Why is my fiber loop coupler tilted?
- How can I make the input- and output into the fiber loop "smooth"? I tried playing around with the angles, but without luck
- Is there a way to make the transition from the combiner to the isolator more "smooth"? I could not find a way to increase the radius of the corner to something more useful
- Is there a way to include an S-shape into the upper output of the output splitter? Apparently setting `fiberangleB=0` did not help

Therefore, are there simple solutions for my issues which I (apparently) did not see in the manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\drawfiber` command can work properly only of you give at least one component to draw from/to, and not only a point. If a component is given by id or name, only then can `pst-optexp` use the component type and its alignment for proper drawing.

So, you should first use only

```
\drawfiber{CompA}{CompB}
```

to draw a fiber between the two nearest points of the two components. If the automatically selected points are not the correct one, like for the connection between the optical isolator and the loop coupler, then you can use `startnode` and `stopnode` to use other component nodes.

A fiber coupler is aligned between the two input and two output nodes. Your `LoopIn` and `LoopOut` nodes caused it to be tilted.

Also note, that you can use different curvatures for start and end of a curve with `ncurvA` and `ncurvB`, respectively.

So, here is your reworked example:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](7,0)(16,6)
        \psset[optexp]{fiber=none, usefiberstyle}
        \newpsstyle{Fiber}{linecolor=orange, linewidth=2\pslinewidth}
        \pnodes(9, 4){TSFIn}(11, 4){TSFOut}
        \pnodes(13, 3){LoopIn}(13, 2){LoopOut}
        \pnodes(9, 1){OutputIsolatorIn}(11,1){OutputIsolatorOut}
        \pnodes(13, 2){OutputSplitter}(16, 3){LaserOutHigh}(16, 1){LaserOutLow}
        %Element 1
        \optfiber[compname=ActiveFiber, position=start,linecolor=red](TSFIn)(TSFOut){Active fiber}
        %Element 2
        \optcoupler[compname=FiberLoopCoupler](TSFOut)(OutputIsolatorIn)(LoopIn)(LoopOut){%
          \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Fiber\\loop\\coupler\end{tabular}}
        %Element 3
        \optisolator[compname=OutputIsolator](OutputIsolatorIn)(OutputIsolatorOut){%
          \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Output\\Isolator\end{tabular}}
        %Element 4
        \wdmsplitter[compname=OutputSplitter, coupleralign=bottom](OutputIsolatorOut)(LaserOutHigh)(LaserOutLow){Output splitter}
        \optfiber[compname=FiberLoop, label=-1.5](LoopIn)(LoopOut){\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Fiber\\Loop\end{tabular}}
        \drawfiber{1}{2}
        \drawfiber[ncurv=1.5, stopnode=1]{2}{OutputIsolator}
        \drawfiber[ncurvA=0.2, ncurvB=1.5, stopnode=2]{2}{FiberLoop}
        \drawfiber[ncurvB=0.2, ncurvA=1.5, startnode=1]{FiberLoop}{2}
        \drawfiber{OutputIsolator}{OutputSplitter}
        \drawfiber[ncurv=1.2]{OutputSplitter}(LaserOutHigh)
        \drawfiber[ncurv=1.2]{OutputSplitter}(LaserOutLow)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

with the output

[image]